# Laravel 4 Virtual Host for Sub-Domain

Tags: laravel-4, virtualhost, document-root

I have a laravel 4 app on my main domain.

However I'd like to redirect a subdomain test.example.com to a the route of the same name (i.e. example.com/test)

Which Document Root am I supposed to use in the Virtual Host configuration File? 
I tried /public/test without success.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with Linode.com

Thanks!
- Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Because `/public/test` isn't actually a directory, you're likely to get errors from Apache if you try to point your subdomain directly to that path (Apache likes things to exist!)

Fortunately, Laravel comes with great Subdomain routing.

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing

One way to do this is to evaluate the 'subdomain' using Route Parameters:

`$subdomain = $route->getParameter('subdomain');`